# When $\lim_{n\to \infty} \log(f_n(x)) =\log\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)\right)$?

Tags: limits, operator-theory

Is there something equivalent to the dominated convergence theorem here? Is it a silly question revealing my ignorance of the commutitivity of the limit operator? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the sequence $(f_n(x))$ converges for a given $x$, then by continuity of $\log$ the relation holds.

Comment: You've answered both of my questions, thank you =D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a property of continuous functions. If $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=a$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(a_n)=f(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n)=f(a)$.

Be careful with your example as $\log(x)$ is not continuous at $x\leq 0$ so if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=0$ for some $x$, then the result doesn't necessarily hold.